# how to access a list declared inside a function from outside without calling the function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, tkinter, button

iam trying to open a file from a location specified  using tkinter askopenfile() method using 'open' button as follows:

```
def open_file():
  file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('text files', '*.txt')])
  if file is not None:
    content = file.readlines()

btn = Button(root, text ='Open', command = lambda:open_file())
```

i want to access 'content' outside the function without calling open_file() to avoid repeating of opening window.i tried this;

```
content = None
def open_file():
  global content
  file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('text files', '*.txt')])
  if file is not None:
    content = file.readlines()
    return content
btn = Button(root, text ='Open', command = lambda:open_file())
print(content)
```

but i get the output as 'None' instead of getting file content. Is there any solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a `if file is not None:` in your function. What happens if that statement is `False`, what will the `open_file()` return?

Comment: You need to call `print(content)` after `open_file()` has been executed, for example a function triggered by another button (of course you need to click `Open` button first), otherwise it will get `None` .

Comment: @BrunoLubascher when file is none,it returns empty list along with None. although,i opened file having text,it returns None.

Comment: @acw1668 as in code, I called print(content) after the open_file() executed.But it also returns none. The content prints when the print is called after mainloop() function executed and after only the tkinter window is closed. all i want is to get the content in the main code after the file opened.

Comment: No, your code has not yet executed `open_file()` when `print(content)` is executed.  You need to study what `event-driven programming` is.

Comment: @acw1668 okay,can you tell what should i do to fix this problem

Comment: I have already told you in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
def open_file():
  global content
  file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('text files', '*.txt')])
  if file is not None:
    content = file.readlines()
    print(content)
  else:
    content = ""
    print(" ")
btn = Button(root, text ='Open', command=open_file).pack()
```

Comment: this also returns None when i try to open files having text.

Comment: Try again Now. It is running. You can also remove 'global content' statement if you don't need that text further.